# Error while calculating an x12 of a time series in R

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

I have a monthly time serie that I am trying to seasonnally adjust via the `x12` package, but I get the following error that I find not very self explanatory although I have ckecked my serie is indeed a time series :

```
Error in readx12Out(file, freq_series = frequency(tso), start_series = start_series,  : 
  An error occured when running x12! Program halted!
```

Here is my MWE with a `dput` table

```
library(x12)

MWE <- structure(c(69.3, 69.4, 69.5, 69.7, 69.9, 70.2, 70.5, 70.7, 70.8, 
                   71.1, 71.4, 71.6, 72.1, 72.2, 72.2, 72.5, 72.7, 72.9, 73.3, 73.4, 
                   73.5, 73.8, 74.1, 74.3, 74.5, 74.8, 74.9, 75.1, 75.3, 75.5, 75.8, 
                   76, 76.2, 76.3, 76.5, 76.7, 76.8, 76.9, 77.1, 77.2, 77.3, 77.4, 
                   77.5, 77.6, 77.7, 77.8, 78, 78, 78.1, 78.1, 78.2, 78.3, 78.4, 
                   78.4, 78.6, 78.6, 78.7, 78.8, 78.9, 79, 79.1, 79.2, 79.2, 79.3, 
                   79.3, 79.4, 79.5, 79.2, 79.4, 79.5, 79.6, 79.6, 79.6, 79.7, 80, 
                   80, 80.1, 80.2, 80.2, 80.3, 80.3, 80.3, 80.2, 80.3, 80.3, 80.5, 
                   80.6, 80.6, 80.6, 80.6, 80.7, 80.8, 80.8, 80.7, 80.8, 81, 80.8, 
                   81, 81, 81, 81.1, 81.2, 81.2, 81.4, 81.4, 81.5, 81.5, 81.6, 81.4, 
                   81.6, 81.7, 81.7, 81.8, 81.8, 81.8, 81.9, 81.9, 82, 82.1, 82.2, 
                   81.967713693352, 81.9418220384609, 82.3993576586313, 82.2876428111403, 
                   82.3456059356801, 82.4205473741361, 82.0691236017988, 82.4479526807796, 
                   82.6400867112465, 82.7205407635895, 82.7368903166171, 82.8089046961582, 
                   82.5365526060594, 82.6841351814674, 83.1197678625341, 83.3466704153293, 
                   83.4777453528701, 83.5602014681842, 83.2708677364797, 83.7502397063261, 
                   84.0023389512661, 84.1216688651068, 84.0651448930737, 84.2678682619126, 
                   84.2259772723727, 84.3473288744301, 84.7901359985743, 84.9800179942922, 
                   85.1188044179191, 85.1945892389009, 84.9720135129594, 85.2878398527536, 
                   85.5671558902957, 85.6192117956492, 85.6027962020017, 85.7530211675084, 
                   85.2677042648555, 85.8800143219216, 86.1465699422324, 86.275085986105, 
                   86.4190188757462, 86.4633274382677, 86.1555810212674, 86.4548937006074, 
                   86.9047828591269, 87.0459891725197, 86.9656330707877, 87.1430947037948, 
                   86.6560380655989, 87.3006837013218, 87.5766890943358, 87.7327651928149, 
                   87.8731938048199, 87.892603588013, 87.5833257833822, 88.070883884196, 
                   88.2262252963144, 88.2303357674243, 88.194203944594, 88.356765677173, 
                   87.7793554255549, 88.2609332400678, 88.6737044173788, 88.7757063887179, 
                   88.8838119545325, 88.8791083826275, 88.3305104433586, 88.88858078423, 
                   89.1510623060071, 89.0585889157837, 89.0343972653786, 89.1834980352787, 
                   88.811139907244, 89.1215670038501, 89.619923356461, 89.8321770631727, 
                   89.925415572456, 89.8824134054159, 89.3646846746944, 89.8520712930934, 
                   90.0334010766246, 90.1102493143106, 90.2204739937508, 90.5147070696261, 
                   89.9956586022078, 90.2637523502633, 90.7497281844847, 90.9858332350394, 
                   91.1156809717273, 91.1352920891032, 90.6116121376265, 91.2123823929658, 
                   91.3544847738102, 91.527750625589, 91.7486363753003, 92.0995381311276, 
                   91.6728516219216, 92.0050010121024, 92.7533251844954, 92.8934337638814, 
                   92.9805057571971, 93.0414379223554, 92.3941792776343, 93.0843873212318, 
                   93.2888322734847, 93.4589510918919, 93.5244315978018, 93.711698189504, 
                   93.1542366374934, 93.5508570751034, 94.1510286410448, 94.2411576577069, 
                   94.3876747872554, 94.3876124675403, 93.7978245678662, 94.574031683045, 
                   94.4589544656395, 94.4278861211887, 94.3460631610389, 94.6556002628982, 
                   93.7636918141619, 94.568118673329, 94.9949819667414, 95.0354225430243, 
                   95.0250925498424, 95.0861250344015, 94.534749665857, 95.1310389697224, 
                   95.2136746492863, 95.2406704304976, 95.1195820424686, 95.3658363209663, 
                   94.6486749316272, 95.0472443538106, 95.8003534041235, 96.1004321415555, 
                   96.1867234067476, 96.3328533752031, 95.4794144273198, 96.3200788737589, 
                   96.3537498102384, 96.5312133733721, 96.6715942430409, 97.1476096489329, 
                   96.3452457453394, 96.6442226096376, 97.6389816111808, 97.7283705577389, 
                   97.8028551383237, 97.9558913317198, 97.034363963525, 97.6956514461773, 
                   97.7563490984791, 97.6540795695839, 97.6515106135986, 97.9828587148281, 
                   97.0997338381585, 97.3088444901448, 98.317102002123, 98.2152945486512, 
                   98.3093675514843, 98.4165530440598, 97.6555752820642, 98.3075230845746, 
                   98.4288045567158, 98.3969450709763, 98.5082465238513, 98.6985323682939, 
                   97.5611201553781, 98.353508613676, 99.1016962240937, 99.1222647142353, 
                   99.042868365113, 99.0182520731131, 98.5371842556533, 99.4917594064962, 
                   98.9243109786632, 98.9045678984094, 98.7330816664243, 99.1862680057582, 
                   97.7177512245616, 98.4063243006257, 99.3151652235298, 99.4434538312378, 
                   99.5894305688091, 99.6193157715815, 99.1588375939513, 99.963607883394, 
                   99.5246016473716, 99.5945674471323, 99.4402242264222, 99.9466028218794, 
                   98.5399253454016, 99.0569898631983, 99.9353749007514, 100.031592897129, 
                   100.153664575076, 100.227541642224, 99.6711301588894, 100.368081190845, 
                   100.111152444148, 100.045529458878, 99.8966064679175, 100.242779629019, 
                   99.0665858544122, 99.1122415566879, 100.252412143228, 100.492367490972, 
                   100.503019460831, 100.656252379047, 100.126478895711, 100.79250404894, 
                   100.558607856437, 100.525643346908, 100.424533861527, 100.832375246272, 
                   99.884702193794, 99.9032762429129, 101.097533908735, 101.261134796911, 
                   101.474423105356, 101.44754065964, 101.029324418162, 101.762921704062, 
                   101.311624885324, 101.340303026902, 101.154772431222, 101.536222485788, 
                   100.631707853325, 100.618645621669, 101.633127323424, 102.05977365584, 
                   102.028388782376, 102.360945956225, 101.902974269494, 102.508963376252, 
                   102.186577964604, 102.297260315903, 102.077921258066, 102.538701762914, 
                   101.656957282898, 101.913120067157, 102.335821458819, 102.366153273144, 
                   102.678482131186, 102.782672029059, 103.32463614954, 103.040520095229, 
                   102.670208330987, 102.529678833559, 102.463579462258, 102.639905722883, 
                   102.669849375064, 102.365056655234, 103.129523284383, 103.256625892897, 
                   103.422511809107, 103.697544076187, 103.298096571774, 104.065964401499, 
                   103.93832652736, 103.993395948694, 104.209378680309, 104.51937548687, 
                   104.410969018222, 104.981800853972, 105.822241166773, 106.534388230208, 
                   107.275029063193, 107.504481707471, 107.855965181766, 109.128111043433, 
                   108.673688612285, 109.128014351595, 109.439207690093, 109.912313381578, 
                   109.702942136744, 110.391496664454, 111.437196831362, 112.240601968719, 
                   112.862279751352, 112.981888392966, 113.058910345135, 114.300261455799, 
                   113.659188689588, 113.847707807461, 113.910171663303, 114.047778326909, 
                   113.511090345461, 113.856120602028, 114.599059653279, 115.088944155289, 
                   115.481588088273, 115.424002262942, 115.332190612272, 116.469889283374, 
                   115.644844136021, 115.692248024515, 115.626653680739, 115.704799425145
), .Tsp = c(1990, 2024.91666666667, 12), class = "ts")


x12(MWE)
```

Comment: Your code `x12(MWE)` is not giving an error for me

Comment: It does indeed work on another computer ; I have not identified where my first environment falts, but happens. I will close in a few days unless someone recognizes the problem or I get more information on my side

Comment: Please check the `packageVersion("x12")` in both those computers in case it is due to a different version